# Chromecast Android TV turn external screen ON

Tags: android, chromecast, android-tv

I'm developing a screen save app for the Google Chromecast, which should be connected to the external screen. And I'm using code to wake up the screen at the specific time defined by the user. It works fine on an android TV emulator.

```
    val power = applicationContext?.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
    val lock = power.newWakeLock(
        PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK or PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                or PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, applicationContext?.packageName + ":wakeup!"
    )

    lock.acquire(0)
    lock.release()
```

But I have an issue with the real device connect to the external TV display. After 15 minutes of inactivity, the TV display goes to sleep, and Google Chromecast cannot wake the TV display.

Is there any way to wake the display?

Google Home application wakes the display with a voice command.

Maybe some access to google home API?

Comment: Since TV display on/off is controlled HDMI-CEC, it may be useful to check: https://source.android.com/devices/tv and https://source.android.com/devices/tv/hdmi-cec But I have doubts about control without being a "privileged process".

Comment: @MorrisonChang I checked HdmiControlService, and it's a private API, and I don't have access to it. 
I think it could resolve my issue if I'd had access to it

Answer (score 0):

I have made my research on it and this is my **answer**:

- do this to know if the device supports the wakeLock level `power.isWakeLockLevelSupported(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK)`,
- I see that your goal is to keep the screen on, strongly consider using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` instead ; this is how you set it in your Activity's `onCreate()` method : `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`
- here is the official documentation: [PowerManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager)

Comment: the goal is to turn the screen on when after it went to sleep.
I use WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON in layout

Comment: Okay, thank you for the precisions. Just need a few more, are you putting your PowerManager code inside a foreground service or an activity ? If it's in an activity, the reason the TV is not waking up might be because Android TV OS is shutting down your App.

Comment: The app is running. 
Chromecast with app connected to TV display via HDMI. 
I need to turn ON the TV display after it went to sleep